# PHP add two numbers in class

Tags: php, class, variables, addition

I'm trying to build a function inside a PHP class, however whenever I invoke the function, I am only returning the first variable.

```
        class Nums  
{
    private $a = 7;
    private $b = 8;

    public function sum() 
    {
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }

    public function __set($name,$value) {
      switch($name) { 
        case 'a': 
          return $this->setA($value);
        case 'b': 
          return $this->setB($value);
      }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
      switch($name) {
        case 'a': 
          return $this->getA();
        case 'b': 
          return $this->getB();
      }
    }

    private function setA($i) {
      $this->a = $i;
    }

    private function getA() {
      return $this->$a;
    }

    private function setB($i) {
      $this->b = $i;
    }

    private function getB() {
      return $this->$b;
    }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here, because I can't really see what is wrong with this logic.

Comment: This looks fine to me. How are you using this class?

Comment: I added the set and get components which I used to modify the class, I didn't think this was the issue. Obviously it was. When I called the sum fuction I was trying to get the private variable, when I should be using the name I defined in the swtich statement.

Comment: yes, sometimes the problem shows up at unexpected places :)

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me. Here's what i tried and it output `15`.

PHP CODE :

```
<?php

class Nums  
{
    private $a = 7;
    private $b = 8;

    public function sum() 
    {
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }

}

$obj = new Nums();
$c = $obj->sum();
echo $c;

?>
```

OUTPUT :

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Nums  
  {
    private $a = 7;
    private $b = 8;

    public function sum() 
    {
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }
  }

$numObj = new Nums();
echo $numObj->sum();
```

Running this code returns 15 for me